# Retrieving value from one column based off max of another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset (SQL Server 2012) I am trying to pull final monthly totals from per account number and summarize the different locations together. I need the final balance number from the last day of the month in YYYYMMDD. Pulling in a min or max won't work because the balance could be higher or lower, but it needs an aggregate for the Group By function. How can you reference the balance?

See the example below, with the goal output below that

```
Account#    Location    Balance    YYYYMMDD   YYYYMM  
     1       South      $400       20171030   201710  
     1       South      $395       20171031   201710  
     1       South      $402       20171101   201711  
     1       South      $408       20171102   201711  
     1       North      $75        20171030   201710  
     1       North      $80        20171031   201710  
     1       North      $80        20171101   201711  
     1       North      $72        20171102   201711  
     2       South      $5,000     20171030   201710  
     2       South      $5,200     20171031   201710  
     2       South      $5,200     20171101   201711  
     2       South      $5,500     20171102   201711  
     2       North      $2,000     20171030   201710  
     2       North      $1,800     20171031   201710  
     2       North      $1,700     20171101   201711  
     2       North      $1,600     20171102   201711  


Account#    Balance    YYYYMM  
     1       $475      201710  
     1       $480      201711  
     2       $7,000    201710  
     2       $7,100    201711
```

Thanks!

Comment: I read the question 3 times and can't figure out how you get those numbers. It looks like you have a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: 10/31 is the last day of the month.So for account 1, it would add $395 (from South location) and $80 (From North Location) for the $475 total. For November, it would add the last date, $408 and $72, for the $480 total.

Comment: That comment was very useful MarkJ and the question makes a lot more sense now

Comment: @MarkJ I think you should add conditions to your question and explain it, that will make the question clear, and you will get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row_number()` is a typical method:

```
select t.*
from (select account, yyyymm, yyyymmdd, sum(balance) as balance,
             row_number() over (partition by account, yyyymm order by yyyymmdd desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by account, yyyymm, yyyymmdd
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @Gordon--I'm confused by how partitioning by 'yyyymm' works instead of by 'yyyymmdd.'  I would think partitioning by 'yyyymm'  and account would add up all values for Account 1 with 201710, which would add $400+$395+$75+$80.

Comment: @jackstraw22 . . .  I have no idea why you think numbers would be added together.  There is no `sum()` or `+` in the query.

Comment: @Gordon---yes, you're correct.  I was overthinking it and looking at the partition being involved in the calculation.